# how to adapt one to many in my controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-3

I have two models (User and Services). What I want is to display all the services of a user. This is my action that show me all the services :

```
public function index()
{
    $services = Service::all();

    // load the view and pass the nerds
    return View::make('services.index')->with('services', $services);
}
```

**and in my User model I add this function :**

```
public function service()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Service');
}
```

**Then in my service model :**

```
public function user()
 {
     return $this->hasOne('User');
 }
```

So please if someone has any idea, I will be very appreciative :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationships you are looking for for a 1-to-many relationship are `hasMany()` and `belongsTo()`.

With that in mind, in your `Service` model, define the relationship like so...

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

It doesn't really matter too much in this scenario because you aren't using it, but it might save you some confusion later.

Now to get the users's services, you can use the `User` model.

`$services = User::find(1)->services;`

Or if you just want to get the logged in users's services...

`$services = Auth::user()->services;`

Comment: thanks, but when i tried that i got this error "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: Oh I see, our methods are different.  Try `User::find(1)->service`.  If that doesn't work, it's likely because you don't have a user stored with id of 1.

Answer (score 0):

In your service model. Notice that you may have to define the local and foregin keys on these relationships

```
 public function user()
 {
   return $this->belognsTo('User');
 }
```

Then you can parse them in your controller or view (only the foreach part) like this

```
$user=User::find($id);
foreach($user->service as $service){
 //do something 
   echo $service->id
}
```